android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG Android Manifest Error
So I'm having Problem with my manifest merger,  play-services-measurement-api and play-services-ads-lite, so I tried adding
<meta-data android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG" android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config" />
to Override the error so the merger can ignore one but it doesn't work
does anyone have a solution to this?
I tried even commenting out ads initialization but it doesn't work,
Here are my Question? If I downgrade my  AGP and Lower my  Google Ads SDK will the error be resolved?
I tried Commenting the Ads out but the error wasn't solved
I tried Lowering the Google Ads SDK to 22.X.X but  it didn't work.
I also tried updating AGP to 9.0 but to no avail.

So Apparently, Android studio builds your app using the latest Dependencies  and libraries, so you have to backdate your Libraries to support your android API
<meta-data android:name="android.adservices.AD_SERVICES_CONFIG" android:resource="@xml/gma_ad_services_config" />

This only works for android 13+
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
so if you are building an anroid 10+ app backdate your ads sdk to maybe 22.X instead of the current 23.X Good luck Devs and hope this helps :)
